# How to nest an array inside another array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I need to nest an array I've created in JSON inside of another array to give it proper formating for [jQuery Datatables library.](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/160/json.aadata-is-undefined/p1)

Here is my current code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: uMtbls,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(jMtbl) {
        $.each(jMtbl, function(i, item) {
            mAll = jMtbl[i];
            mOwn = jMtbl[i].OrigOwner;
            mPub = jMtbl[i].PublicationTblNm;
            mTbl = jMtbl[i].TableId;
            mMig = jMtbl[i].MigrationFreq;
            mGTYPE = jMtbl[i].GTYPE;
            exec();

        });

        oTable = $('#dtManaged').dataTable({
            "bStateSave": true,
            "bProcessing": true,
            "bServerSide": true,
            "aaData": jReform,
            "aoColumns": [{
                "sName": mOwn,
                "sTitle": "Original Owner",
                "sWidth": "10%"
            }, {
                "sName": mPub,
                "sTitle": "Table Name"
            }, {
                "sName": mTbl,
                "sTitle": "ID"
            }, {
                "sName": mMig,
                "sTitle": "Migration Frequency"
            }, {
                "sName": mGTYPE,
                "sTitle": "Oracle Gtype"
            }],
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "iDisplayLength": 25,
            "aLengthMenu": [
                [25, 50, 100, -1],
                [25, 50, 100, "All"]
            ]
        });
    }
});

function exec() {
    jBld = mOwn + "," + mPub + "," + mTbl + "," + mMig + "," + mGTYPE;
    //console.debug("[" + mOwn + "," + mTbl + "]");
    jReform = jBld.split(",");
    console.debug(jReform);
}​
```

The output looks like this (captured in console.debug):

```
["text","text","text","text","text"]
["text","text","text","text","text"]
```

The sample should be:

```
{ "aaData": [
  [ 10126, 10002253, 415 ]
]}
```

Comment: Why don't you decode the JSON to a Javascript variable and then manipulate the data however you want?

Comment: that's what I'm currently doing. I'm having a problem nesting the array that I'm creating inside another array to make the data into the format that is required

Comment: Then please show only that code. The AJAX aspect is then irrelevant. Show ONLY the code that is necessary.

Comment: You don't know how to use arrays in any way, the `exec()` function is proof of it. That's no way to create a fixed length array

Comment: how..where exactly is your output coming from?

Comment: I'm currently capturing the output in the console

Comment: I know, but is it coming from a file? your server response? hardcoded?  If it's coming from your server, it's probably easiest to format it there

Comment: It would help if you posted what you have tried so far.

Comment: its JSON from the server and I didn't write the service. The guy that wrote it is telling me to format it on my side... The JSON is outputting objects which is what I'm converting over from strings to arrays(bc the datatable format needs the arrays)

Comment: Oh ok.. can you show the exact json string that is returned? it looks like you are getting two separate arrays - but I can't really tell by the post

Comment: Object {Title: "Name", Title: "Name", Title: Number}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Array.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push). And make use of the [`var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) statement, you are creating a hell of global variables.

```
var aaData = [];
$.each(jMtbl, function (i, item) {
  aaData.push([
    item.OrigOwner,
    item.PublicationTblNm,
    item.TableId,
    item.MigrationFreq,
    item.GTYPE
  ]);
});
```

```
oTable = $('#dtManaged').dataTable({
  ...
  "aaData": aaData,
  ...
});
```

(Note: the links are not only for show, please read through them.)

Comment: Thanks! I don't get a chance to have my code reviewed(ever) so I'm wild wild west, which isn't a good thing...thanks that solved my issue and I'll be doing some reading tonight